# right click --> run python script + exposed variable from Context Menu

Tags: python, directory, contextmenu, right-click

I am looking for some help to run a python script inside a folder when I right click + run example.py, that can get the current folder path when I right clicked and move files to specific folders. then I want my script to pick that path and continue executing the script.
The scripts works by itself, but I have to manually input the path every time I run it (which isn't ideal).
I managed to add the shortcut to context menu and run the script, however I don't know how the script can pick the current path without me allocating it to a variable. (basically to get the PATH of current folder)

In the Registry editor I added a new key that points to python location and example.py file.

Computer\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell
value: C:\Python\Python372\python.exe "c:\temp\example.py"

this is what I have done so far. (I am a beginner in python). Please let me know if you can help!

many thanks

```
import os
import shutil
import glob

PATH = r"c:\temp\example.py"
ext_filter = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'bmp']
IMAGES = []

for x in os.walk(PATH):
    for ext in ext_filter:
        for y in glob.glob(os.path.join(x[0], '*.' + ext)):
            IMAGES.append(y)
for img in IMAGES:
    shutil.move(img, PATH + "\\" + "IMAGES" + "\\" img.split("\\")[-1])
```